# How to change the number format to data d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to change the number format to date.

For this model using numbers it is working: ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8LIpOBbP40jEInFr?preview))

```
data in csv:
name,start,stop 
task1,1970,2000 
task2,1985,2003 

d3.csv("data.csv",function(players){
  console.log("csv",players)
  players.forEach(function(d){d['years']=[];  });
  d3.range(1950, 2016).forEach(function(year){
    var currentHeight = 0
    players.forEach(function(d){ 
        if (d.start <= year && year <= d.stop){
            d['years'].push({year: year, height: ++currentHeight})
            if (d.stop  == year) d['stopHeight']  = currentHeight
            if (d.start == year) d['startHeight'] = currentHeight
        }
    })
})
```

I'm trying to change to date format: ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SkqiKqaCBVE5uzRd?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview))

```
    name,start,stop
    a,23/01/2020 00:03:44,23/01/2020 00:04:38
    b,23/01/2020 00:04:03,23/01/2020 00:17:44
    c,23/01/2020 00:04:05,23/01/2020 00:10:37

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y %X").parse;
d3.csv("data.csv",function(players){
players.sort(function(a){ return players['start']})

  players.forEach(function(d){
        d['years']=[];
  });
    d3.time.minute.range(d3.min(players, function(d) { return parseDate(d.start); }), d3.max(players, function(d) { return parseDate(d.stop); }))
        .forEach(function(year){
    var currentHeight = 0
    players.forEach(function(d){
        if (parseDate(d.start) <= year && year <= parseDate(d.stop)){
            d['years'].push({year: year, height: ++currentHeight})
            if (parseDate(d.stop) ==year) d['stopHeight']  = currentHeight
            if (parseDate(d.start) <=year) d['startHeight'] = currentHeight
        }
    })
})
```

The height value is not showing correct. What can I do to change the height?

Console.log shows:  attribute d: Expected number, "….61354019746122,NaNH137.99012693…". when I use: if (parseDate(d.start) ==year) d['startHeight'] = currentHeight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no console errors in your plunker #2

Comment: that is because: parseDate(d.start) <=year, if you put parseDate(d.start) ==year, then you will see the error...

Comment: if you put console.log(d3.max(players, function(d) { return currentHeight  ; })).. you will see the max is number is 5.. this number is not showing in c.y.domain..

Comment: to reduce use the console.log(d3.max(players, function(d) { return d['startHeight']   ; }  in the line 47..